# Highcharts Highmaps issue with Bower installed files

Tags: jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I installed Highcharts with Bower. I am now trying to load highcharts and highmaps on the same page. I read in their docs that I need to load as follows:

```
<script src="../../js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/highcharts/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

This all loads OK, but the map fails to load without an error.

Same for this combination, no error but no map:

```
<script src="../../js/highcharts/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

If I replace the above with:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

The map works perfectly. What have I missed? I want to load from a local copy the `highcharts` and `highmaps` code. Thanks

Comment: The first one should work. No JS errors in any case? This is strange. Are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: Hmmm, the links to the local copy installed with bower do not work. I have tried compiling with gulp into a single file and the result failed too. I need both Highcharts and Highmaps on the same page. Weird, as it is a bower install.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any errors in JS console? There should be something :) Like not loaded module, Highcharts error or JS error.